# Adding Day to sepcial Date with Duplicating count of friday

Tags: vb.net

Im trying to make Recursive Function in VB.net

The Function are going to add some day to Special date . also if there is a
friday between the range of added day its going to count them and adding them to
date again.

it must be Recursive because if there way a friday after adding more than 7 day
it also must add another day to date.  like this :

> origianl date :  5/19/2015
>   day to be added : 30
>   added date :  6/18/2015
>   count of friday between 5/19/2015 and 6/18/2015 : 4
>
> new date after adding fridays : 6/22/2015
>   count of friday that happen after addinf old friday count : 1
>   new date and final result : 6/23/2015

i think the last two step must be recursive. this what ive done so far without last two step :

```
   Public Function CountOfFriday(ByVal StartDate As Date, ByVal DayToAdd As Int32) As Int32
        Dim newDate As Date = StartDate
        Dim OriginalDate As Date = StartDate
        Dim friday_count As Integer
        For value As Integer = 1 To DayToAdd
            OriginalDate = OriginalDate.AddDays(1)
            If OriginalDate.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Friday Then
                newDate = newDate.AddDays(1)
                friday_count += 1
            End If

        Next
        Return friday_count

    End Function
```

and im adding the result of this count to my old date.

now how can i achieve last two steps ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This returns the final date (hope it helps)

```
Function CountOfFriday(ByVal StartDate As Date, ByVal DayToAdd As Int32) As Date
    Dim newDate As Date = StartDate
    Dim OriginalDate As Date = StartDate
    Dim friday_count As Integer = 0
    For value As Integer = 1 To DayToAdd
        OriginalDate = OriginalDate.AddDays(1)
        If OriginalDate.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Friday Then
            Do
                friday_count +=1
            Loop until StartDate.AddDays(DayToAdd+friday_count)<StartDate.AddDays(friday_count*7)
            Exit for    
        End If
    Next
    newDate = newDate.AddDays(DayToAdd+friday_count)

    Return newDate

End Function
```